# how can configure queue agent in Adhearsion-Asterisk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, asterisk, adhearsion

I want to know how adhearsion 2.3.5 create asterisk config generator for queues such as new agent 
and auto generate queues.conf ...

config_generator = Adhearsion::Asterisk::ConfigGenerator::Queue.new

asterisk_config_file = "queues.conf"

How does this work .. any help would be appreciated

Comment: That question is very hard to read, you might want to clarify what exactly you’re asking and what research you've done.

Comment: I want to know create queue without editing queues.conf using adhearsion .. According to doc                                                 config_generator = Adhearsion::Asterisk::ConfigGenerator::queue.new
asterisk_config_file = "queues.conf"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably later, but anyways...
The queue configuration generator is deprecated and possibly non-functional.

We have moved away from platform specific code towards a more standards based approach with Rayo (http://rayo.org).

There is still space for specific code but in the end you are better off just writing queue.conf yourself.

That said, and with the little information you offer, the generator does not "create queue without editing queues.conf" - it will just give you a preconfigured queue.conf that you still have to put in /etc/asterisk.